# Django ImageField not uploading the image

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I'm developing a simple game webstore. The idea is that developers can upload games that will be displayed on an iframe (so the games are simply just URLs) and then they can be played.

The problem is, when publishing a game, the icon image does not get uploaded. So the image cannot be displayed.

The Game model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    developer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default="images/default_game_img.png")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    published = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

I use a Django ModelForm:

```
class PublishForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'url', 'price', 'icon']
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={
                'cols': 80,
                'rows': 4,
                'class': 'form-control'
            }),
        }
```

The form is generated simply like this:

```
<form class="form-horizonal" name="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}

        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my view that is used here:

```
def publish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PublishForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            g = form.save(commit=False)
            g.developer = request.user.username

            g.save()

            profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            profile.owned_games.add(g)
            profile.save()

            return render(request, 'shop/published.html')

    else:
        form = PublishForm()

    return render(request, 'shop/publish.html', {'form': form})
```

The URL of the image is correct, but the image itself does not get uploaded. 
Even if I manually move the image there, it won't be displayed if I put it as the source for and image on html.

On settings.py I have the following lines:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to urlpatterns?

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much, this fixed it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to urlpattern:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

See details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Answer (score 9):

There are multiple things that you should check when the image isn't showing/saving.

- 1 - You're missing a request.FILES parameter.

  2 - You've made changes to the model but haven't made migrations yet.

  3 - Django couldn't create a folder to place the images in(never
  faced this problem)

  4 - There's a typo in your HTML form; especially here:
  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`; `(I once wrote multipart/form instead of multipart/form-data)`

  5 - If you're using some old Django version then you'd have to
  manually add the following code in your `urls.py` file: `python urlpatterns = [] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

  6 - There's always a possibility that your filename is extremely
  lengthy and it causes some unexpected behavior.

Comment: 4 was what got me. I forgot to add that attribute to the form.